# EXTJS4: MVC - How to reload store with an interval

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, store, setinterval

I have a controller and I want to refresh the store after 5 seconds automatically with an interval.
Where do I have to put this reload in?
I tried to put it in the init:function.
Maybe the code is wrong? Ist doesn't work.
Here is my code from the Controller:

```
...init: function() {
this.control({
    'mygrid': {
        run: function(){
            Ext.getCmp('MyGrid').getStore().load();
            console.log("akt");
        },
        interval: 5000,
        itemdblclick: function(rec, el) {
       ....
```

Comment: You don't tell us if it worked or why it didn't. Also you didn't paste all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, i solved it. I put this into the object. Thanks for this hint Lorenz Meyer.

```
...render: function() {
        makeInterval = setInterval(function() {
        Ext.getCmp('MyGrid').getStore().load();
        }, 5000);
    },...
```

Comment: Dont forget you have the inbuilt Ext JS task manager to help with things like this: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskManager

Comment: And where do you define this? In the controller? init:function?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not correct syntax.

The object `'mygrid' : { ... }` must contain [valid events](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) for a grid. `run` and `interval` are not event names, while `itemdblclick` is.

You could set the interval on `render` event, and then unset the interval on `destroy` event.